JQGrid Header Filter of Filter
I have used free JQgrid4.15.1 version and took help from some of below portals for implementing and creating a JQgrid table with inline edit functionality.
[1]: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610359/JqGrid-Inline-Editing 
[2]: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822405/Using-jqGrid-in-an-MVC-Web-Application-2 
[3]: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules 
[4]: https://praneethmoka.wordpress.com/tag/jqgrid/ https://free-jqgrid.github.io/ https://github.com/free-jqgrid/free-jqgrid.github.io

In the table there are drop-downs in header to filter the results, which is working perfectly fine.
While when filter table data based on 1 header filter the filter is not getting applied on other drop-down filters mean those drop-down should also have reduced no of selection available based on current table data. I need help here to achieve this functionality in JQGrid Table.
If anyone can share any recommendation it will be helpful.
